# In a VPN, how to access resources inside a connected office from the VPN server

Tags: vpn, rras, l2tp, tp-link

I have this Windows Server running on AWS, running a VPN with RRAS and NPS. The initial setup included only SSTP, and the users could easily connect from their Windows computers on their homes and use the shared folders on the server.

Later we decided to connect the office to the server using L2TP, with a TP-Link TL-ER6020 router, and it was incredibly easy to achieve: on the router I expanded "VPN", clicked on "L2TP", then on the "L2TP client" tab and added the connection (for the "Working Mode" I chose "Routing"), and then noticed that the IPsec settings were already set up automatically. The computers on the office can now access the shared folders on the server, and I even added the office computers to the Active Directory domain running on the remote server.

So, the part about accessing the server seems to be going fine, but what about being able to access resources on the office from the AWS remote server? For testing purposes, using the SSTP connection from my home computer, I am able to connect to a web page (Duplicati) running on my home computer from the AWS server, but cannot ping my home computer or access a shared folder on it, even after turning the VPN connection to "Private", but that would be a bonus question: the real question is how to access resources located on the office (the L2TP VPN) from the AWS server, with the TP-Link router in the middle of the way.

I did not use DHCP on the VPN server, only the "IPv4 address assignment" on RRAS, and the "static address pool" is 192.168.10.1 to 192.168.10.100: the TP-Link router connection gets a dynamic address of this pool that I can see on the RRAS interface. On the office side, the subnet is 192.168.1.0/24, with the TP-Link router acting as the DHCP server.

What do I have to do? Do I need to create static routes on the server or something like that, or do I need to do something on the TP-Link router (or both)?

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Great that you managed to solve it. But please, post your solution as an answer in the box below and accept it. Otherwise the question will stay as "unanswered" in the system forever. It is perfectly fine to accept your own answers.

Answer (score 0):

I already figured it out, I just added a route "route ADD 192.168.1.0 MASK 255.255.255.0 192.168.10.100" on the server, with "192.168.10.100" being the reserved IP address of that particular remote VPN client, the TP-Link router.

To reserve the IP address in RRAS: I launched NPS > Network Policies, double clicked my VPN policy and unchecked "Ignore user account dial-in properties", then, I was able to assign a static IP address in the "Dial-in" tab of the user I use to connect to the VPN.

P.S. I marked the question as answered by myself, but it just stopped working after some time. I', not able to access resources on the office from the VPN server anymore.